# Mongodb Object_id in Spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with mongo database.
I created the entity so that the id of the document is stored as an Object_id.

```
@Document(collection = "projects")
public class Project {

@Id
private String id;

private String name;

}
```

Now i want to get timestamp and the id string from mongo object_id.
Can this be done in spring boot ?

Answer (score 0):

`org.bson.types.ObjectId` has 2 methods : `getTimeSecond()` and `getTime()`

Comment: i need to declare it as ObjectId in the entity instead of String ?

Comment: You can get the needed information like this : new ObjectId("mongo_id_as_string"); and call one of the 2 methods.

Comment: i'll try that what about getting the string from the object_id for example get "60e76c4a239e87ef38414bc9"  from { "_id" : ObjectId("60e76c4a239e87ef38414bc9") }

Comment: When you get the MongoDB document from the "Projects" collection, you have to call .getId() immediately and this way you will get the Id as a String value.

Comment: Please, post this clarifications as a part of your answer via [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68313662/edit). This will improve it's usefulness and allow readers to understand *how* to do, not just *what* to do

Comment: @AmineSafi The method getTime() from the type ObjectId is deprecated

Comment: You can use getDate() otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful example for above types of cases.

```
@Query(value = "{ 'field1.field2' :  ?0 }" )
List<Pojo> findById(ObjectId id);
```

Reference
https://tw.coderbridge.com/questions/736a1611bbb94320a4f923660097a588