# Using the ID value object of an aggregate for persistance with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, domain-driven-design

A classic DDD rule is that aggregates should reference each other via their ID, and that the ID of an aggregate should be a value object. So something like this (in Java):

```
class MyAggregate {
    private MyAggregateId id;
    private String someOtherField;
    ...
}

class MyAggregateId {
    private UUID id;
}
```

How can i make MongoDB use MyAggregateId instead of the autogenerated ObjectID? Is that possible?

Bonus points if the answer involves doing this with spring-boot, where i hoped i could just declare `public interface MyAggregateRepository extends MongoRepository<MyAggregate, MyAggregateId> {}` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: You can always use your `id` along side with mongodb's `_id`, or you can use an ObjectId as your UUID

Comment: If i go the first route i can't do use any of the `XYZbyId`-methods, right? And would then have to implement those? How would i go about the second route, code-wise?

Comment: For the first route, I don't think this is important, these are all wrappers. For the second one you can create a mongodb `ObjectId` using spring (I'm using mongoose and it is easy there), and use it in your code before inserting to the db. I prefer the first route.

Comment: Oh definitely not important, more of a convience thing. Do you have a link or something for the second one? I'm completely new to mongodb and still somewhat to spring, so that would be very helpful :)

Comment: Looks like: `ObjectId objCompany = new ObjectId();`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313573/mongodb-object-id-in-spring-boot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568054/how-to-convert-a-biginteger-to-objectid-with-spring-data)